# Set Theory : Proof regarding subsets and relative complement

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove the following logical equivalency :

( *A* ⊂ *B* ) ≡  *A* \ *B* = ∅

My solution : If *A* ⊂ *B*, then *x* ∈ *A* → *x* ∈ *B*

Lets define the relative complement as a set *A* \ *B*  := { *x* ∣ *x* ∈ *A* *and* *x* ∉ *B* }

There is no *x* that fulfills this condition. Therefore ( *A* ⊂ *B* ) → *A* \ *B* = ∅. Now lets show that   ( *A* \ *B* = ∅ ) → ( *A* ⊂ *B* ). Lets prove this by contradiction. Assume that ( *A* \ *B* = ∅ ) is true. We can write this as a statement :

There is no  *x*  ∣ *x* ∈ *A* *and* *x* ∉ *B*

Now lets assume that the negation of ( *A* ⊂ *B* ) is true. This is written as :

∃ *x* ∈ *A* and *x* ∉ *B*.

This is clearly a contradiction, which means the implication is always true. We have now proven that ( *A* ⊂ *B* ) ≡  *A* \ *B* = ∅. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

> Since this set is not defined for any $x \in A$, it means this set is always identical to the empty set $\emptyset$.

It doesn't really make sense to say the *set* $A\setminus B$ is not defined for any $x \in A$. I think what you mean to say is that the condition "$x \in A$ and $x \notin B$" is not satisifed for any $x$. Therefore no $x$ can be an element of $A \setminus B$.

Now all this shows is that $A \subset B \Rightarrow (A \setminus B = \emptyset)$. But you also need to show the other direction: start by supposing $A\setminus B = \emptyset$, and use this to show that $A \subset B$. Then you will have shown the equivalence between the two.

Comment: Ok. I'll edit the post after I've completed the proof as you have suggested.